# ES6 Modules, stop execution of code

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

It sounds like an odd question: **How can I leave the execution context from an ES6 module?**

See the following example:
Module1 requires some features in the browser to be present (say some new stuff not every Browser implements currentl).

You want to do a check in the module, if the required feature is available and if not, you want to stop the execution.

When writing that with an immediate function call, you can just call `return` and the following code is never executed.

How to do that in an ES6 module? Do I have to wrap the whole code into an `if` block?

Comment: depends on what you're exporting. If you're exporting a function, then you can.... return from it like you've mentioned, otherwise you could export something else if it's not supported.

Comment: What does the module do? What things does it export? What (other) things should it export when these features are not available? Or: should the module be loaded at all if they are not available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you export executable code from an ES6 module, you usually do so as a function:

```
export function myFunction() {
    ...
}

---

import { myFunction } from './module';
myFunction();
```

This function works just like any other that you define directly in the calling module. You can simply `return` to the caller as you would otherwise:

```
export function myFunction() {
    if(...) return;

    ...
}
```

Comment: In my case I am exporting a function but continue adding properties to the function. I dont want to do that, if its not working anyway. So the check is more or less outside of the exported function

Answer (score 1):

There's no special tools (that I'm aware of) in ES6/ES2015 to do this. Furthermore, all exports must be top-level. This also means that if a module ever has a given export, it will **always** have that export. The value of that export can change, of course, but the export "interface" must always be the same.

If you don't want to export certain values if a condition isn't met then you won't be able to do that. However, you can always make those values `null` or `undefined` in that case. If exporting isn't a problem, there are a few tools from ES5 and before that you can use.

The IIFE (as you know):

```
(function() {
  ...
  if (someCondition) {
    return;
  }
  // code that won't run
})();
```

A single iteration `for` loop (no idea why you'd use this but you could):

```
for (var i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
  ...
  if (someCondition) {
    break;
  }
  // code that won't run
}
```

And a good old-fashioned `if` statement:

```
...
if (!someCondition) {
  // code that won't run
}
```

Comment: Might be good to include an example of updating or changing the exported value, since that's not obvious to people new to the syntax.